# add a column showing number of records for that ID before a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has a column called START_DATE which is of type datetime, and the id is represented by ID. I want to find the number of records in the same table, for that person before that START_DATE.

This is my attempt

```
select ID,count(*) from dbo.MyTable
where START_DATE < (select START_DATE from dbo.MyTable)
group by ID
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data and desired results.  The question doesn't really make sense.  If a person has multiple records, then the person (presumably) has multiple start dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
SELECT t.ID,t.start_date,max(t.OTHER_COLUMN),max(T.OTHER_COLUMN2)...,count(*) from dbo.MyTable t
INNER JOIN dbo.MyTable s
ON(t.id = s.id and t.start_date > s.start_date)
GROUP BY t.ID,t.start_date
```

Or with a correlated query:

```
SELECT t.ID,
       t.start_date,
       t.OTHER_COLUMN,
       t.OTHER_COLUMN2,
       ......
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.MyTable s
        WHERE t.id = s.id and t.start_date > s.start_date)
FROM dbo.MyTable t
```

Comment: it works great. But just that, I want to select/display all the other columns in t/s as well. Basically, I want to add a new column. When I do something like select t.*, t.patient_IEN,t.ADMIT_DATE, it gives me the Column 'dbo.someothercol' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. How can I edit it to display other columns as well?

Comment: @PepperBoy I've updated my solution, both solution should work, the second one works for sure.

Comment: I have one more question. I have a series of START_DATE for the same Id and along with displaying other columns, I want to add a new column which finds the difference between the START_DATE for an Id(person), and his next START_DATE. I tried doing this as follows : SELECT t.Id,t.START_DATE,(select top 1 s.START_DATE from dbo.MyTable t
INNER JOIN dbo.MyTable s
ON(t.Id = s.Id and t.START_DATE > s.START_DATE)
GROUP BY t.patient_Id,t.START_DATE)

Comment: Please post a new question, it is hard to read and understand like this and the question was already closed..

Comment: Okay have added it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848788/adding-a-column-which-calculates-days-until-next-event